# Why is this cell appearing outside my table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding an input element to my HTML table with Javascript like this:

```
    var nameCell = row.insertCell(0);
    nameCell.innerHTML = data[i].Title;
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    if (data[i].COMPLETED == true) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
    } else {
        checkbox.checked = false;
    };
    row.appendChild(checkbox);
```

But the input is appearing outside the table:[image]

How can I fix this?

Notice that the checkbox is indeed part of the row, which I've highlighted in gray. My only issue is that the row lines don't extend to the full width of the row.
[image]

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, you can probably replace the entire if/else with checkbox.checked = data[i].COMPLETED;

Comment: @palaѕн What do you mean by complete code? ALL of my code? That would be big and impractical. I figured I'd just provide the problematic code.

Comment: @Your code has problem in only one line `row.appendChild(checkbox);`

Comment: @Amit I'm well aware of that, I just needed to provide reference as to how I was setting it up. No one would understand what I'm doing if I didn't include the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append the checkbox to the row instead of to the cell.

It is, therefore, a sibling of the cell.

The cell takes its normal place in the row, which means the row has to be extended to allow the cell to be placed next to the cell.

Comment: Shouldn't the Bootstrap lines extend to fit the new cell though?

Comment: What does Bootstrap have to do with it? (Hint: Provide a [mcve], also look at the rendered structure in the Element Inspector in your browser and see what CSS is applied to what elements).

Comment: I want two separate cells though, I don't want to add it to an existing cell.

Comment: Doing something with the cell you are creating would probably be a good idea then.

Comment: I added that title to the first cell in the second line. I'm trying to add a second cell for the checkbox.

Comment: Append it to the row! Don't append the checkbox to the row!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the input to the last td of the row :

```
var nameCell = row.insertCell(0);
nameCell.innerHTML = data[i].Title;
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
if (data[i].COMPLETED == true) {
    checkbox.checked = true;
} else {
    checkbox.checked = false;
};
var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
var lastcell = cells[cells.length -1];
row.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Comment: Should you not add checkbox to lastcell HTML. You also appended it to table row.

Answer (score -1):

Container inside a table is table cell, not table row. Put it inside the row, and HTML table would not be able to render it correctly. Put it inside the table cell, it will appear as per format.

[Bootstrap’s grid system, and most of layout system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content. These containers, rows and columns are created through css classes through elements like div, span, nav etc. It does not use HTML table for grid system layout. So, it will not be able to structurally place your checkbox correctly for visual rendering, when not added to table cell.

Use colspan if you want to design with HTML table. Apply proper width to table and cells, and append checkbox to table cell.

To a row, you can append a container cell. But you should not append another element to a row which will have its own visual representation. If appended to table row, while rendering, browser would not know where to place it inside the table bounds.

["Row groups convey additional structural information and may be rendered by user agents in ways that emphasize this structure"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)